# delete records from salesforce using java rest api post method

Tags: salesforce

Can I delete multiple records in salesforce using java rest api?

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(instanceURL
                    + "/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Note/delete/"+listofIds);
            post.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + authToken);
HttpClient httpClient = ProxyAuth.getLocalProxy();
            int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete multiple records by creating Post Url Like this :

```
String str = '';
for(String st : listOfIds){
    str += 'id='+st+'&';

}
str = str.substring(0 , str.length());
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(instanceURL
                    + "/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Note/delete/records?"+str);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Seems like this no longer works? When I call `/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Contact/delete/records?id=...&id=...&id=...`I get the error message: "Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: delete"